# How to count events using year and plot line graph in d3.js v3

Tags: d3.js

I would like to ask how to plot a line chart using data from a csv file.

I have successfully created a line graph using a csv file from a sample data set and plotting them using a data value that represents its frequency.

eg. 
Date            Frequency
Jan 1 2000  39.81
Feb 1 2000  36.35
Mar 1 2000  43.22
Apr 1 2000  28.37
May 1 2000  25.45
Jun 1 2000  32.54
Jul 1 2000  28.4
Aug 1 2000  28.4

Next what I want to do is, to just use the date, and base from the year of the date, count how many events are there for a corresponding year.

for example : 
Date (this is the actual date format from the csv)
10/20/2016
10/25/2016
11/17/2016
1/25/2017
3/13/2017
4/13/2017
4/21/2017
5/4/2017
5/3/2017
6/2/2017
6/2/2017
6/8/2017
6/8/2017
6/12/2017

so for year 2016 I have 3 events or frequencies. for 2017 I have 11, and then use the result to plot it on the line graph.

Is this possible ?

note : I'm using d3.js. v3

I'm using a different CSV file in data set 1 and data set 2

I have tried and successfully implemented a code similar to the one found in the link

https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/line_several_group.html

SAMPLE CODE:

```
parseDate = d3.time.format("%b %d %Y").parse;

incidentline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function (d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function (d) { return y(d.frequency); });


d3.csv('/samplegraphdata.csv', function (error, data) {

     data.forEach(function (d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.frequency = +d.frequency;
    });

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.date; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.frequency; })]);
```

The Expected result should be a line chart that has the year(s) on the x axis as and count on the y-axis.

And the data is being read from a CSV.

I have no actual results yet on my end because for now I'm just trying to figure out how to do this.

---

Im Sorry about the format of the dates from the CSV

it should be like this

[dataset1 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9a5z.png)

(this is the actual format)

Here is the sample result

[sample Graph Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ET1Fs.png)

this is the data format for data set 2

[dataset 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bEjP.png)

I'm sorry if my question is difficult to read, I'm usually posting in stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I actually successfully tallied the data.

THis is the solution

```
    data.forEach(function (d) {
        var splitdate = d.Date;
        console.log(d.Date);
        var year = splitdate.split('/')[2];


        tally[year] = (tally[year] || 0) + 1;
        console.log(tally[year]);

    });

    var data = [];

    for (var year in tally) {
        if (tally.hasOwnProperty(year)) {
            data.push({
                year: year,
                frequency: tally[year]
            });
            console.log(data);
```

My question is how Can I sanitize the x-axis to reflect the correct year.

I don't know why is became .016 .017 etc

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7P6U.png)